# Finding largest prime that divides an integer that is equal to sum of the squares of its four smallest positive divisors

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

Sorry about the title... wasn't sure what to put??
My question is:
A positive integer is equal to the sum of the squares of its four smallest positive divisors. What is the largest prime that divides this positive integer?

I have played around with it a bit, and have got no where. I was hoping to not need to just sub values in or solve intuitively. How do you solve this question, and is there a general route to this type of question?

Comment: There is a square missing in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n$ be that integer and $1,u,v,w,\ldots, n$ its positive divisors in ascending order. Then we have
$$\tag1 n=1+u^2+v^2+w^2.$$
Assume $n$ is odd. Then $u,v,w$ are odd and $1+u^2+v^2+w^2$ is even, contradiction.
Therefore $n$ is even and hence $u=2$.
Now $v^2+w^2=n-5$ is odd, hence one of $v,w$ is even and the other is odd.
The following cases are possible:

- $v=4$ and $w$ is odd (and $\ge5$). Then $w^2+1\equiv 2\pmod 8$, whereas $n-u^2-v^2$ is a multiple of $4$, contradiction
- $v=3$, $w=4$. We arrive at the same contradiction
- $v$ is an odd prime and $w=2v$. Then $n=1+4+v^2+4v^2=5(1+v^2)$ is a multiple of $5$. As $w\ge 6$, we conclude $v=5$, $n=130$.

Checking the only solution $n=130$, we find that the largest prime divisor is $13$.